# Hidden items in top menu bar

Tags: rest, global-navigation

I have a hidden item in the top navigation bar shows in the photo[image: Photo]

Using the rest api, my url is

```
http://<site>/_api/web/navigation/TopNavigationBar
```

It returns with the hidden item. How can i prevent this?

Comment: These API's are provided out of the box. We can't modify any of those service. What is the actual usecase in this requirement?

Comment: use the top nav bar in a custom designed page

Comment: Just check JSOM and see if it gives back a visible property

Comment: Here is a IsVisible property, but it always gives a true value

Comment: Yes I know this is a bug in REST API that is why I requested to check JSOM